# Which player has had the most consecutive appearances in MLB's All Star Game?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

What player or players has the most consecutive appearances in the All Star game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hank Aaron** holds the record for most consecutive All-Star Game appearances with 25 games. He appeared in every All-Star Game held from 1955 to 1975, a period of 21 seasons. There were two All-Star Games played in 1959, 1960, 1961, and 1962.

[Baseball Reference - Hank Aaron Statistics](http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aaronha01.shtml)